# Part of scrollview should have scrolling disabled SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a `ScrollView` layout as shown in photo.

[image]

Is it possible and how could you achieve the following in SwiftUI:

- Green square area does not react to scroll gestures but is part of the `ScrollView` and will scroll with red squares
- The rest of the screen (red square area) react to scroll gestures as usual.

The reason is ask this it that in green square area I am trying to add a `SpriteView` that will handle its own touch events and I don't want `ScrollView` to prevent this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found is to create your own ScrollView, as shown below.
It might be easier to tackle with UIKit.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var dragAmount = CGFloat.zero
    @State private var dragPosition = CGFloat.zero
    
    @State private var dragging = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            VStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .fill(.red)
                    .frame(height: 300)
                    .overlay(
                        Text(dragging ? "dragging red ..." : "")
                    )
                    .offset(y: dragPosition + dragAmount)
                
                    .gesture(DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { _ in
                            dragging = true
                        }
                        .onEnded { _ in
                            dragging = false
                        }
                    )
                
                ForEach(0..<20) { _ in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        .fill(.green)
                        .frame(height: 100)
                }
                .offset(y: dragPosition + dragAmount)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        dragAmount = value.translation.height
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        withAnimation(.easeOut) {
                            dragPosition += value.predictedEndTranslation.height
                            dragAmount = 0
                            dragPosition = min(0, dragPosition)
                            dragPosition = max(-1750, dragPosition)
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```